# JPA join multiple table one to many and one to one

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have this 4 tables on Oracle DB

> FACTORY_MASTER
>
> FACTORY_DETAILS
>
> LOT_MASTER
>
> LOT_DETAILS
>
> **Relations**
>
> FACTORY_MASTER **1 - N** FACTORY_DETAILS
>
> LOT_MASTER **1 - N** LOT_DETAILS
>
> FACTORY_DETAILS **1 - 1** LOT_DETAILS

This is the current implementation of Model class

```
public class FactoryMaster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "factory_master_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "factory_master_gen", sequenceName = "seq_factory_master")
    @Column(name = "FACTORY_MASTER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FACTORY_MASTER_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "FACTORY_MASTER_ID",
                nullable = false)
    private List<FactoryDetail> details;

}

public class FactoryDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "factory_detail_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "factory_detail_gen", sequenceName = "seq_factory_detail")
    @Column(name = "FACTORY_DETAIL_ID")
    private Long id;

    // I exclude on purpose ManyToOne, because you cannot have FactoryDetail without a Master

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "factoryDetail")
    private LotDetail lotDetail;

}

public class LotMaster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lot_master_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "lot_master_gen", sequenceName = "seq_lot_master")
    @Column(name = "LOT_MASTER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOT_MASTER_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "LOT_MASTER_ID",
                nullable = false)
    private List<LotDetail> details;

}

public class LotDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lot_detail_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "lot_detail_gen", sequenceName = "seq_lot_detail")
    @Column(name = "LOT_DETAIL_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FACTORY_DETAIL_ID",
                referencedColumnName = "FACTORY_DETAIL_ID")
    private FactoryDetail factoryDetail;
}
```

I need to extract the **factory_master** using **lot_master_id**

So the query would be

```
select distinct fm.*
  from factory_master fm
       join factory_details fd on fd.factory_master_id = fm.factory_master_id
       join lot_details ld on fd.lot_details_id = ld.lot_details_id
       join lot_master lt on ld.lot_master_id = lt.lot_master_id 
 where lt.lot_master_id = :ID
```

How can get the same result via JPQL valid?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be using a cross join like this would help:

```
select distinct fm 
from

FactoryMaster fm 
    inner join fm.details fd 
    inner join fd.lotDetail ld1

,LotMaster lm 
    inner join lm.details ld2 

where 
    ld2.id = ld1.id
    and
    lm.id = :lotMasterId
```

Comment: Alternative to crossjoin?
Since I got the relation one to many between LotMaster and LotDetails, is possibile to join via child without adding the bidirectional mapping - manyToOne, so adding the parent in LotDetails
Thanks

Comment: The above query does not require you to add the FactoryMaster in FactoryDetail (i.e. many-to-one bidirectional mapping).
Infact, if you had done that, then you wouldn't need the cross join. You could then achieve the requirement using:
select distinct fm 
from

LotMaster lm 
    inner join lm.details ld
    inner join ld.factoryDetail fd
    inner join fd.factoryMaster fm

where 
    lm.id = :lotMasterId

Comment: Using the suggested query (not CrossJoin) I have to set the many-to-one bidirectional mapping as you said, but I cannot have FactoryDetail without a Master that's why I excluded since the beggining the bidirectional mapping. If the only way to achieve is the crossjoin I'll go this way

Comment: Cross Joins are considered bad from performance point. And adding LotMaster in LotDetails wouldn't cost much. So the better approach would be to go the bidirectional way and use the query with just inner joins.

Comment: However, even If i wanted to avoid bidirectional because I don't need navigational access in both directions and other performance risk
Seems like the only solution
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query(value = "select distinct fm.*from factory_master fm
join factory_details fd on fd.factory_master_id = fm.factory_master_id
join lot_details ld on fd.lot_details_id = ld.lot_details_id
join lot_master lt on ld.lot_master_id = lt.lot_master_id 
where lt.lot_master_id =:#{#Id}", nativeQuery = true)
List<FactoryMaster > getFactoryMaster(@Param("Id")Long Id);


u can use like this
```

Comment: Without using native query, is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible u can mention native query=false

Comment: HQL? Could u provide an example? Thanks?